# Debugging Matlab avoids memory leak

Tags: matlab, debugging, memory, memory-leaks

I have a memory intensive Matlab script. 
What puzzles me is that if I run this code it will leak memory at the very first iteration (out of the 46 expected). The leak will eventually become so big that it will require forcing Matlab to quit:

[image: massive leak at the first iteration]

Trying to find the leak point, I set a breakpoint at the first line in the loop but as I hit "Continue" the execution ran through the first loop and stopped again at the breakpoint and produced no leak. Removing the breakpoint and continuing from that point reintroduces the leak.
Using the breakpoint to execute the code one loop at the time avoids the leak and the code terminates with no issues (fig.2).

[image: no leak when debugging the same script]

Now, I would like to:

1) understand whether this leak is due to something I introduced or whether it could be a Matlab specific issue,

2) get an idea of how to find the leak (I cannot use the debugger as it removes the problem).

I would love to provide the code but it is quite a big chunk (>100 lines), so my question is more about the general approach than the actual debugging of the specific issue.

Comment: interesting, did you pre-allocate your matrices before the loop? Also, does anything in your loop gets bigger with each iteration? i.e. a vector that grows in size with each iteration?

Comment: I do preallocate what I can outside the main loop. There is a nested loop and I preallocate before that within the main loop. So I am overwriting on the first matrix redefining it as zeros at each loop.
EDIT: forgot to answer the second question. No, nothing increases really.

Comment: if your on PC you can utilize the `memory` and `whos` function to do some old fashioned printing information to the screen during the normal (no debug) execution to see if you can "debug" it.

Comment: I don't have a real solution, but just some thought what I would try. 1) Use `keyboard` instead of the debugger, maybe you can reproduce the behaviour. 2) Write a logfile with the memory used and the corresponding line of code. 3) Try `pack` at random places in your code. 4) Move the computation within your loop into a function which is called for each iteration.

Comment: I am on osx so I cannot use memory but thank you for suggesting. I will try the whos, the pack and the keyboard. Also the log at each stage and the external function are good ideas. I'll post the answer as soon as I understand what is going on. Thanks

Comment: I like @Daniel 's 4th suggestion, let us know what happens.

Comment: A growing memory use is not identical to memory leaks. Are you using any external binaries/mex files which are maybe causing this issue? I think it is unlikely some Matlab builtin is leaking memory. It will be much easier to help you if you provide some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.
My approach has been to isolate the portion of code that was causing the problem with printouts above each line of code so that before the leaky crash I could see where the execution stopped.
The culprit was a `zeros(100k)` line where I tried to pre-allocate a big matrix.

I tried executing the same line on a newer version of Matlab (2015b vs 2014b) and found that while the older version lets you instantiate big matrices (over ~ 50k by 50k) and freezes when it sucks all the memory, the newer version returns the following error:

> Error using zeros
>
> Requested 50000x50000 (18.6GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. 
>   See array size limit or preference panel for more
>   information.

In my case the limits for a NxN matrix are:

N > ~60000 on Matlab2014b on 16GB RAM

N >= 46341 on Matlab2015b on 12GB RAM

With the difference that my 2014 version lets me at least try to create them and collapses when they are too big and the 2015 version prevented me from trying at all.

The puzzling bit is that, on the 2014b version, if I debug the code the compilers lets the `zeros(100k)` line run and everything works just fine.
The problem appears again if I try to visualise the contents of the matrix in Matlab `Variables Tab`.

Comment: It is very often the case that debuggers let you do things that runtime won't -- not just in MATLAB.   I recall a famous case at Msoft Word developers, where they were trying to find a crash error, but in their debugger the limit on open files was Inf, rather than the value assigned to runtime Word app.   Took them a while :-) to track that down